# Add property to a Feature Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-pro

I want to add the key property *"class: 1"*  to my FeatureCollection.

This feature of adding a class / value key is done automatically when you create a FeatureCollection and add a property by using the "Geometry Import" tool in the Earth Engine map area.

[image]

```
var toList_pasto = ee.List([
          pasto_10,
          pasto_11,
          pasto_12,
          pasto_13,
          pasto_15,
          pasto_16,
          pasto_17,
          pasto_20,
          pasto_19,
          pasto_21,
          pasto_18
]);

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
  if (i == 0){
    randomSamples = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(toList_pasto.get(i),500)
  }
  else {
    randomSamples = randomSamples.merge(ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(toList_pasto.get(i),500))
  }
}
```

In my code, I want to do this in the line 28.
[Add Property in FeatureCollection](https://code.earthengine.google.com/61f1d33c09a42c526b57be1febee5aa6)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use 'set'. It can set a property to the whole featurecollection:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
  if (i === 0){
    randomSamples = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(toList_pasto.get(i),500).set('Class', i)
    print('Collection number: '+ i, randomSamples)
  }
  else {
    var newCol = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(toList_pasto.get(i),500).set('Class', i);
    print('Collection number: '+ i, newCol)
    randomSamples = randomSamples.merge(newCol) 
  }
}
```

However, as you are merging all your featurecollection into one big collection, you probably want to set every single feature with a property 'class'. Therefore, you have to map over a (server-side) list with the length of the number of geometries you have. We then map inside the mapped list over each collection and set the property to every individual feature:

```
// Map over a list equal to the amount of geometries
var FeatCol = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(0, toList_pasto.length().subtract(1)).map(function(i){
  // get the geometry corresponding to the number
  var pasto = ee.Geometry(toList_pasto.get(ee.Number(i)))
  // make random samples. Map over the collection to give each feature a class name
  var randomSamples = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(toList_pasto.get(i),500).map(function(feat){
      return feat.set('Class', i)
    });
  return randomSamples;
// return the flattened collection of collections
})).flatten();
// print limited to 5000 otherwise it won't print
print(FeatCol.limit(5000))
```

[Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8b467d232c939986de3d2e78a19c9de0)

Comment: Thats works incrediable fine to me, thank you so much!

Comment: Dear, Kuik, I've tried to reproduce this lines of code to anothers FeaturesCollections in the same script. But I get an error about global variables declare in JavaScript. Can you help me?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/031733ff9aaab2e50553179ec3f979e3

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f5931c3294330123c700ff99d043cdd9 see comments

Comment: Thanks for the contributions.
I have identified that after applying the ".sampleRegions", the value set to "class" is not added to the new collection.
I checked this when giving a print after applying the ".sampleRegions" at line 97.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d3ba4d51e4b9c9d2c87fd840b4f3661