# How to add a new property to each element in a feature collection using a map statement

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to map over a feature collection and set a new property called 'id' for each element in the collection. I made a list 'feature_id' which contains the id names. The code runs and the id property is set but they're all zero.

[image]

I am trying to figure out a way to iterate through my list within my map statement, so that the first feature id is 0 , second is 1, etc... I thought using a counter would work but it resets every iteration. There also might be an easier way to do this but I had trouble finding one.

```
//combSlabs is a feature collection containing 5000 fields
var sizeSlabs = combSlabs.size().getInfo()

//create Id (System:Index) for each of the different fields
var feature_id = []
for (var i = 0; i <= sizeSlabs; i++) {
    feature_id.push(i)
}

var getId = combSlabs.map(function(feature) {
  var counter = 0
  var add_id = feature.set({id: feature_id[counter]})
  counter += 1
  return add_id
})
```

Comment: That's weird, I ran it with a fake featureCollection and had no issues with the id numbers https://code.earthengine.google.com/11b73b26a1724476475087f5753c46e9

Comment: @MadeleineNicolas Yeah I tried it with a different feature collection and you were right. It seems the Feature Collection I was working was acting weird and ran fine with different feature collections. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to stick to server side processing as much as possible, so here is an example with everything server side. The answer comes from another similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316991/add-property-to-a-feature-collection) in stackExchange, there you can also find a client-side version. There was no working example so I had to come up with something for myself, but it boils down to this:

```
var newList = idList.map(function(x){
  
  var index = idList.get(x)
  var feat = toList.get(x)
  
  return ee.Feature(feat).set('id', index).copyProperties(feat)
})

print(newList, 'newList')
```

You iterate over a featureCollection that you turn in list (such that you can use .get()) and return it as a feature in the new collection.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/8cb66ee3b3840ee7f059e75573c2228b

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I read the similar post you linked above and it makes more sense to stick with the server-side analysis like you mentioned.